# Command pattern vs Queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have gone through the command patterns and learned that it can hold different commands on list. So why it is constructing a complicated structure when we have simple collection classes like stack or queue. why no queue is used in command pattern?

[Reference for command pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8303/Using-the-Command-pattern-for-undo-functionality)

```
 Queue q = new Queue();

     q.Enqueue('A');
     q.Enqueue('M');
     ch = (char)q.Dequeue();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you think the two directly correlate.  The Command Pattern specifically addresses how to solve communication issues between senders and receivers.  I also don't understand why you think the queue can't/isn't used with the Command Pattern.  Oftentimes it is quite the opposite, it IS utilized.

Comment: As per my understanding command pattern defines how we can preserve the request for future use.

Comment: That is only one piece of the Command Pattern's purpose.  There is also the ability to define a request as a particular object and the ability to manage the relationships between a request and various receivers based off of whatever parameterization is required.

Comment: thats only for the concept of undo/redo

Comment: At the end of the day you're comparing a data structure to a pattern and asking why you have the pattern instead of just the data structure.  The data structure merely can aid in the pattern fulfilling its job.  They are not direct replacements for one another, nor should they be.

Comment: Actually, the linked example uses nothing but a simple Stack.

Comment: @user1357872 I am also thinking about this... what is your final conclusion for this question?

Answer (score 1):

The article you've linked DOES use a `Stack` for the `UndoableCommand`s:

> `class CommandManager
>      {
>          private Stack commandStack = new Stack();
>      ...`

However, the use of a `Queue` indicates commands coming in from the user and being sent to the command processing system, which would help to continue making the form responsive while commands are executing. This is in effect Asynchronous Programming<sup>1</sup> which goes well beyond the scope of this one article.

<sup>1</sup>Normally, I'd link an article here, but the subject of asynchronous programming is so vast that I honestly believe you're better off googling it and looking at multiple sources.